# how to escape jquery click event in Asp.net mvc action link?

Tags: jquery

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Remove from cart", "RemoveFromCart", new { id = item.RecordId }, new  {  @class ="remove" })%>
```

The rendering of this action  is :

```
<a href="/JqueryTest/Delete/23" class="Delete-item">Delete</a>
```

And i have the JQuery code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.remove').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                success: function (data) { alert('ok') },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                },
                               });
```

What i want is, when i click delete link, I lunch an  ajax request
without responding to click event (without goining in /JqueryTest/Delete/23 page ).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default action of browser.

```
$('a.remove').click(function (event){
   event.preventDefault();
})
```

|Also `$(this).attr('href')` might not work inside ajax function, change it to

```
var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: myurl,
    success: function (data) { alert('ok') },
    error: function () {
    alert('error');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a `return false` in the end of your click function.